# Find time complexity of a nested loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

For the loop below,

```cpp
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        sum++;
```

what is the time complexity and how should I think? My guess is that the outer loop runs a total of `log(N)`. The inner loop runs `N` times. Therefore, the time complexity should be `Nlog(N)`.

Am I correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first loop, the number of iterations is equal to `log2(N)`, as `i` is doubled every iteration.

For each iteration of the first loop, the second loop runs for `N` times.

Therefore overall time complexity = `(log2(N) * N)`, where the function log2(x) = log(x) to the base 2.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand. But what if the inner loop looks like this: `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)`, where I changed the `N` to `i`?

Comment: I assume it's only O(N) then, because the inner loop runs `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + (N-1)` times. Am I right?

Comment: For  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++), it will be 1+2+4+8+16 ... = 2^(N-1) ~ O(2^N).

Comment: My bad @belismau, I corrected my comment. You got it right. It is the summation of geometric progression.